# How to overwrite a value for a custom field?

Tags: custom-field

I have created a custom value called *source* it is retrieved inside a theme where it goes  `href=""` place. Now when I want to add a new value to *source* in the Post, it just adds up to the value instead of replace that value I entered.
By adds up, I mean that when I hover over the image, the `href` have two links that I entered.
Here is how I retrieve the value:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,"source",TRUE); ?>" target="_blank">
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</a>
```

I know how to delete it from the database, but this for a novice use that will barely be able to do that. Any advice ?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I initially didn't find a way to make the post's thumbnail image get a `href`, for that matter I used thought of this way.

Comment: Where is the code that saves the data?

Comment: when I go to every post, in the bottom the custom field is there, I just add new _source_ and later when I come back I just use update. But currently for the posts that was posted before adding that meta-key, they seem to have that default value which I can not over-write

Comment: You are using the default "Custom Fields" box? The behavior you describe is non-standard. You should only get one of the values you enter, not both "added" together.

Comment: @s_ha_dum yes, I'm using the default "Custom Fields" box. The only problem is that I can't set default value, or let's say replace the default value. so for example I have this post submitted and it gets default value of :
[link]http://localhost:8080/wp/wordpress/2013/08/read-blog/
now after I add value to the value, the _href_ becomes
the link + whatever I enter.

Comment: Got it. Give me a second. I see the problem.

Comment: This guy explains it here:
[link]http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83578/can-you-set-a-default-value-to-a-custom-field

He says define it in the `post_meta` That must be in functions file. Now I just need to figure out what default value wouldn't mess the thing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the problem is with the workings of the custom meta field (look into the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). The issue is with the use of relative URLs, whether you realize that that is what you are doing or not.

Left empty, `<a href="" target="_blank">` is by default the page you are on. Likewise, `echo '<a href="'.get_post_meta($post->ID,"nada",TRUE).'" target="_blank">Hi</a>';` defaults to the page you are on if there is no 'nada' meta key. If there is a key, then the link ends up looking like this:

```
<a href="yourkeyvalue" target="_blank">
```

That is a relative URL and will be converted by the browser to "the page you are on" plus "yourkeyvalue". There is where you are seeing things "added" together.

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I think it is something like this:

```
$url = get_post_meta($post->ID,"source",TRUE);
if (empty($url)) {
  $url = get_permalink();
} else {
  // make an absolute URL
  $url = site_url($url);
} ?>

<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank">
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</a><?php
```

The only catch is the line following `// make an absolute URL`. I don't know exactly what kind of information you are inserting or what kind of cleaning/validation/manipulation you need there.

If you only want to print the link if there is a source value then use this:

```
$url = get_post_meta($post->ID,"source",TRUE);
if (!empty($url)) { ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank">
  <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
  </a><?php
}
```

Your `source` meta value ***has to be*** an absolute URL-- `http://example.com/whatever`. ([You can probably get away with a protocol relative URL.](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/))

Comment: I wish I could up vote your answer. I took your snippet and started troubleshooting, but I realized that, each and every `<a href=""> </a>` get the `get_permlink();` right away, even If I don't define it. Now I don't know how to avoid that.

Comment: I think you missed the point. The point was about avoiding the relative URLs. Do you want to print the link only if there is a `source` meta_value?

Comment: yes, that was my point, but when I retrieve the link it becomes like this:
`<a href="thePermLink + source"><img> </a>`

Comment: Pretty sure you did miss the point of the answer. See the edit.

Comment: My Apologies, Thanks so much for your help! the part I missed was **// make an absolute URL**.

This is what it looks like now and it gives me the clean url with nothing added on to it:

`$url = get_post_meta($post->ID,"source",TRUE);
   if (empty($url)) {`
     $url = get_permalink();
   } else {
    
     $url = "https://www." . $url;
   } `