# Update Post metafield of specific categories

Tags: post-meta

I have some meta fields in WordPress created by theme and i want to update it by using php.

The metafield stores url and i want to add some string after current url in custom meta.

i tried these method
[Assign/update the custom field value for all posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/270472/assign-update-the-custom-field-value-for-all-posts)

and made changes

```
'post_category' => array(14,16,19);
```

to select a particular category but it edited all posts of all categories.

and used this method to change meta field but it removed url and changet field.

```
$dealcode = "&deal_code=coupon";
    $urlvalue = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'metakey', false);
    $urlvalue = $urlvalue . $dealcode;
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'metakey', $urlvalue );
```

please can anyone fix this.
Thanks.

Comment: Is that meta assigned for posts or for categories? Could you show the rest of your code? It's pretty hard to guess, what exactly are you doing with that `'post_category' => array(14,16,19);`

Answer (score 0):

OK, so a little bit of guessing is involved in that answer, since you've posted only parts of your code, but... I assume that your code looks like that:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_category' => array(14,16,19)
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    $dealcode = "&deal_code=coupon";
    $urlvalue = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'metakey', false);
    $urlvalue = $urlvalue . $dealcode;
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'metakey', $urlvalue );
}
```

If so, then the problem lies in this line:

```
'post_category' => array(14,16,19);
```

There is no `post_category` [argument for WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)...

The correct argument is `category__in`, so your code should look like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'category__in' => array(14,16,19)
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    $dealcode = "&deal_code=coupon";
    $urlvalue = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'metakey', false);
    $urlvalue = $urlvalue . $dealcode;
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'metakey', $urlvalue );
}
```

PS. Since you only use IDs, there is no point in getting whole posts. It would be much more efficient if you used `fields => 'ids'` in your query.